# AWS Lambda Layer magical credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-secrets-manager, identity-management

I have deployed a lambda layer in one account (Account A) and granted access to the rest of the organization, including numerous other accounts, as follows:

```
aws lambda add-layer-version-permission \                                                            
--layer-name my-layer \
--version-number  21 \
--statement-id allOrganizationAccounts \
--principal "*" \
--organization-id o-man-o-man \
--action lambda:GetLayerVersion
```

There is code in the layer that makes `boto3` calls to `secretsmanager`.  The secrets are stored in Account A, that owns the layer. When the layer is attached to a lambda in another account in the organization, say, Account B, it *seems* as though the calling function in Account B can obtain the secrets stored in Account A without having explicit grants or credentials.

Is this an artifact of the layer permission, or is this an indication that there is a policy somewhere enabling Account B to access Account A secrets.  I am reasonably confident there are no credentials embedded in the code.

Answer (score 0):

The lambda layers/extensions have access to the same resources as your lambda functions. It's because they are executed within the same environment as the lambda functions. As a result, permissions are shared between the function and the extension. Thus, ensure your lambda function in AccountB has access to the secrets in AccountA.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-extensions.html#using-extensions-permissions